# What Type of Join to Use in this Search?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query that is bound to a datagrid:

```
select 
  distinct  a.Person_ID, 
            a.Person_Last_Name, 
            a.Person_DOB, 
            CASE 
              WHEN a.Person_Last_Name IS NULL 
                THEN '' 
              ELSE CONVERT(varchar, a.Person_Last_Name) 
            END 
            + ', ' + 
            CASE 
              WHEN a.Person_First_Name IS NULL 
                THEN '' 
              ELSE CONVERT(varchar, a.Person_First_Name) 
            END 
            + ' ' + 
            coalesce(a.Person_Suffix,'') 
            + ' ' + 
            coalesce(a.Person_Middle_Name,'') 
            + 
            CASE 
              WHEN a.Person_Archived='T' 
                THEN ' (Archived)' 
              ELSE '' 
            END 
            + 
            CASE 
              WHEN a.Person_Deceased='T' 
                THEN ' (DECEASED)' 
              ELSE '' 
            END AS PersonName 
FROM PERSON a 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANY c 
    ON a.Person_Company_ID = c.Company_ID
```

I need to also pull up an image for each person when one is available (but display 'None' when no image is available). There are potentially multiple images for each Person - I only want to select the first one. However, there are also possibly no images on file, in which case a default value should be populated. Here is the current SQL statement to fetch images for Persons:

```
SELECT 
  PImage_Path 
FROM PIMAGE 
  WHERE PImage_Subject_ID=@Subject_ID
```

When no images are available, however, I would like it to return 'None' as the value of PImage_Path and not restrict the original select statement from finding Persons with no image. What type of join should I use? How would this query look?

Comment: You could use `OUTER APPLY` with `TOP` (or `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`). What I can't follow is why you have joined `Company` if you don't use it anywhere. And why `Person_Last_Name` and `Person_First_Name` need to converted to `varchar`, what are their datatypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something along these lines, courtesy of OUTER APPLY:

```
select 
    --A bunch of stuff
    ISNULL(pic.PImage_Path, 'None') AS PImage_Path
FROM PERSON a 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANY c
    ON a.Person_Company_ID = c.Company_ID
  OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1
      PImage_Path
    FROM PIMAGE 
    WHERE PIMAGE.PImage_Subject_ID = a.Person_ID --Fix this if I'm making the wrong assumption about your key columns.
    ORDER BY ... --Something sensible to determine which picture will be used
  ) pic
```

Comment: I need to list PImage_Path in the select list somehow so that I can bind it to the datagrid. I don't think this will do that for me.

Comment: You mean with a column alias? (I just updated the code.)

Comment: This is a search query and a bunch of conditions are joined at the end dynamically, so trying to see if this will still work (I can always just add this at the end if not).

Comment: I keep getting SYNTAX errors.

Comment: hang on, I think I figured out the issue (my problem, not yours)

Comment: Disregard, your query works perfectly (I just stuck it in the wrong place (it's a dynamic query in VB.NET). Thanks!

Comment: I guess the `WHERE PIMAGE.PImage_Subject_ID =` should be `WHERE PIMAGE.PImage_Person_ID =` or something similar.

Comment: @ypercube Yeah, I had to just guess at that part.

Comment: @ypercube no that wasn't the issue (I didn't use my actual table names in this question, so I already knew I needed to modify all of this). The problem was that I am dynamically adding an additional `and` statement to the first join and where clauses thereafter, and I put the `outer apply` in the wrong place initially (it needs to be between the `and` clause pertaining to the previous join and the `where` statement(s). Thanks!